# Edit Peer Review process broken

Tags: discussion, edits

Edit: Some people have marked this as a duplicate of "When should I make edits to code?" - this is not the question I am asking, nor what the discussion is about.  The edit was valid and approved.

Recently I was using some code from a helpful answer and realized it wouldn't compile due to a small error.  The author had accidentally used a variable out of scope and the class variable should have been used instead.

Seemed like a simple fix so I submitted and edit to the answer to correct it.  The edit was [rejected](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/23942317) by two reviewers for the reason "*This edit deviates from the original intent of the post. Even edits that must make drastic changes should strive to preserve the goals of the post's owner.*"

Knowing it was correct, I submitted the [same edit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/24189115) again.  It was rejected by one reviewer for the same reason, before finally being approved by the original author.

I see the root of the issue being two issues:

1. The reviewers are not peers - that is to say they aren't knowledgeable on the subject they're reviewing.  The answer involved the language Delphi which none of the three reviewers seemed to have any experience in
2. The reviewers are not reviewing the changes.  The change was correct and needed and anyone reviewing it properly should be able to see that.  Rather than skipping a review it seems the reviewers just pick a rejection option to make it go away.

There are some potential solutions.

1. People selected for peer reviews should have experience in the area they're reviewing.  If it's an answer tagged with "Delphi" then they should have contributed to other answers tagged with "Delphi"
2. Similar to a system slashdot had with "meta-moderation", some sort of audit process would be good to establish if users are actually reviewing edits or they're just hitting the reject option to clear the queue

Comment: Your first edit summary doesn’t say that you’re just fixing a typo. It says you “updated” the class name. You’re allowed to fix typos in answers but you have to say that’s what’s happening in your edit.

Comment: Also, the audit system you want already exists. Note that robo-reviewers spam the Accept button; rejecting an edit takes an extra step.

Comment: @BSMP, it seems the audit system if it exists is broken.  The people that reviewed and rejected the valid edit are top contributors - if there was really an audit system them unqualified reviewers such as them would be prevented from taking such actions

Comment: What you suggest *can’t scale*. The post author, presumably a subject expert,  an already override an edit decision (accept a rejected edit, or reject an accepted edit), that works well enough without clogging the review queues.

Comment: Well it's clear that no one is interested in fixing process failures and any attempt to do so is just met with down votes.  Looks like this site is going the same route Wikipedia did where bureaucracy and gatekeeping rules

Comment: @kbickar please note that short of one proposal discussed many times (require rep/tag restrictions in reviews) and suggestion to implement existing feature there is nothing new to discuss in the post. Unfortunately there is not way on meta to distinguish between "not useful" (which I strongly suspect most votes are here) and "this feature-request is bad idea". I don't think "no one is interested in fixing process failures" - unfortunately this post did not provide any practical  suggestions to do so. Just discussing "should X be improved" is absolutely pointless.

Answer (score 6):

Your explanation of why you were making the edit could have been more informative instead of simply

> Updated class var name

Realizing that there is a fine balance between not enough and too much information about why an edit is being made, in this case more information would have been helpful and could have eliminated the rejection.

Comment: Indeed. "Updated class var name from X to Y, because <insert reason here>". If you don't know how to fill "insert reason here", the edit is probably wrong.

Comment: The second time I submitted the edit I included more information because I realized reviewer aren't always familiar with the language they're reviewing, but it was the same result.

Comment: @kbickar No, the result wasn’t the same; your edit got accepted.

Comment: @MartijnPieters The first person to review it rejected it for the same reason.  The only reason it was accepted was the original author saw it

Comment: @kbickar ^^ Exactly. The **author** approved it. Editing answers is always touchy, especially the *code*. Reviewers have to assume that the author of an answer knew what they were doing. The better approach would have been to leave a comment for the author, pointing out the typo, giving the author the chance to correct it. And others trying to use the answer should see the comment, as well. If all else fails, it's also possible to post one's own answer.